# Define printing mode in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

is there any possibility to set in the tinymce editor what pages need to be printed in landscape mode and what pages we want in portrait.

We are looking into a solution to make that work. We are exporting to word and it would be extremely useful if we could enter the different printing modes before exporting.